# Dart - WebSocket.readyState always returns WebSocket.OPEN

Tags: websocket, dart, flutter

Basically, I'm trying to check the status of my WebSocket `Server.ws`. However, when I query `Server.ws.readyState`, the only response I ever get is `WebSocket.OPEN`. How do I check if a WebSocket is disconnected if it always returns `WebSocket.OPEN`?

For example, I've tried to turn off the WiFi of the device used to test the Flutter app. Normally, after one second, the WebSocket is assumed disconnected and the connection is closed with a `WebSocketStatus.GOING_AWAY` close code. I assumed it would also change the `WebSocket.readyState`, but that doesn't seems to be the case.

So, how do I properly check the status of my WebSocket?

How I'm currently checking :

```
/// Connection status
IconButton _status() {
  IconData iconData;

  switch (Server.ws?.readyState) {
    case WebSocket.CONNECTING:
      print("readyState : CONNECTING");
      iconData = Icons.wifi;
      break;
    case WebSocket.OPEN:
      print("readyState : OPEN");
      iconData = Icons.signal_wifi_4_bar;
      break;
    case WebSocket.CLOSING:
      print("readyState : CLOSING");
      iconData = Icons.signal_wifi_4_bar_lock;
      break;
    case WebSocket.CLOSED:
      print("readyState : CLOSED");
      iconData = Icons.warning;
      break;
    default:
      print("readyState : " + Server.ws.readyState.toString());
      break;
  }

  return new IconButton(
    icon: new Icon(iconData),
    tooltip: 'Connection Status', // TODO:Localize
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        Server.ws.close();
      });
    },
  );
}
```

Additional info about the WebSocket :

```
/// Should be called when the IP is validated
void startSocket() {
  try {
    WebSocket.connect(Server.qr).then((socket) {
      // Build WebSocket
      Server.ws = socket;
      Server.ws.listen(
        handleData,
        onError: handleError,
        onDone: handleDone,
        cancelOnError: true,
      );
      Server.ws.pingInterval = new Duration(
        seconds: Globals.map["PingInterval"],
      );

      send(
        "CONNECTION",
        {
          "deviceID": Globals.map["UUID"],
        },
      );
    });
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error opening a WebSocket : $e");
  }
}

/// Handles the closing of the connection.
void handleDone() {
  print("WebSocket closed.");
  new Timer(new Duration(seconds: Globals.map["PingInterval"]), startSocket);
}

/// Handles the WebSocket's errors.
void handleError(Error e) {
  print("WebSocket error.");
  print(e);
  Server.ws.close();
}
```

Comment: Are you using a websocket library?

Comment: I am using the [WebSocket class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/WebSocket-class.html) from the [dart:io library](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-io/dart-io-library.html). Nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone ahead and taken a look at the source code for the WebSocket implementation.  It appears that when the WebSocket is being closed with the status `GOING_AWAY`, the internal socket stream is being closed.  However, it is possible that this event does not propagate to the transformed stream which handles the `readyState` of the instance.  I would recommend filing a bug report at [dartbug.com](http://dartbug.com).

Comment: I've filled an [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/32876), but the template doesn't make me feel like it's the right place to report. It just asks for [r/MaliciousCompliance](https://www.reddit.com/r/MaliciousCompliance/).

Comment: @NatoBoram That's definitely a pessimistic way of looking at it, but I can assure you that it's the right place to file bug reports for Dart.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the pingInterval, this checks for connection status every said interval, then the closeCode will update